# update function to ask parameter to display stats as required

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to add one more parameter in my function to display stats like min,max,mean, median. for example if i want to display only mean median
the function is working fine but also want to add one more parameter like to display stats as required.

t1(data = listd,var = "sale",name = "listd",stats=c(mean,media))

```
df <- data.frame(Name = c("asdf","kjhgf","cvbnm","rtyui","cvbnm","jhfd","cvbnm","sdfghj","cvbnm","dfghj","cvbnm"),
                 sale=c(27,28,27,16,14,25,14,14,19,18,28),
                 city=c("CA","TX","MN","NY","TX","MT","HU","KL","TX","SA","TX"),
                 Dept = c("HH","MM","NN","MM","AA","VV","MM","HU","JJ","MM","ZZ"))
```

Comment: Two options: (a) have the `stats` argument match the computed column names, always calculate all stats, and do a `select()` at the end using the `stats` arg to only select and return the requested ones, or (b) have `stats` be a list of functions and use `across()` and the `.fns` argument to apply them (probably one `across()` call to calculate the stats, and then another one for your rounding and formatting).

Comment: how it works i never used stats argument,  i have  tried select(" ",N,everything())  names in everything at the end also

Comment: Instead of `everything()` You'd do something like `select(all_of(c("N", stats)))` -- but you will need to match exactly.  Currently your capitalization is not consistent, with `"median"` in the `stats` argument and `"Median"` as a column name, not to mention `"mean"` vs `"Average"`.